# Javascript ? operator: how to pass multiple parameters

Tags: javascript, if-statement, operator-keyword, ternary-operator

EDIT: I have to make this work on IE11

I have the following code:

```
span.classList.add(span.textContent === '\ ' ? 'char' : 'spaceChar')
```

It is working fine, but I would like to add 2 classes in case it's true, something like this:

```
span.classList.add(span.textContent === '\ ' ? 'char','animated' : 'spaceChar')
```

I tried using brackets but had no luck:

```
span.classList.add(span.textContent === '\ ' ? ('char','animated') : ('spaceChar'))
```

Is there any way to achieve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You can add multiple classes with `classList.add` by passing additional arguments, so one option is to use arrays as the conditional expressions, and spread them into the `.add` call:

```
span.classList.add(
  ...(span.textContent === '\ ' ? ['char','animated'] : ['spaceChar'])
);
```

This is equivalent to

```
if (span.textContent === '\ ') {
  span.classList.add('char', 'animated');
} else {
  span.classList.add('spaceChar');
}
```

The first version might be terser, but IMO the second version is a lot more readable.

IE11 [does not support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList#Browser_compatibility) multiple arguments for `classList.add`, so even if you [Babel](https://babeljs.io/repl) (which is the usual go-to tool for turning ES6+ syntax into ES5), so you'll have to add each class separately:

```
if (span.textContent === '\ ') {
  span.classList.add('char');
  span.classList.add('animated');
} else {
  span.classList.add('spaceChar');
}
```

For larger number of class names, you can also use a helper method which takes an array and calls `.add` with each.

Comment: Sorry, it has to work on IE11. I guess I'll stick with the classic if statement.

Comment: Yeah, since IE11 doesn't support multiple parameters there, there's no way to use the single `classList.add` call that you're looking for